# Changing the type of an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

The problem basically consists on this, we have created an Array of Object ArrayLists because we don't exactly know what we will save there until later, but we know how(We HAVE to make it this way), so the default creation on the constructor method initializes it as
`private List<Object> collection`                                          but later on some input will change it, say it to a string, so the AL on the position should be something like       `collection[i] = new ArrayList<String>()` but the compiler says that `ArrayList<String> cannot be converted into ArrayList<Object>` even thought I am pretty sure String, Integer, etc inherit from the class Object
Anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `collection[i]` for? Just `add` to the collection

Comment: collection[] is the array that will be filled with ArrayLists, but they refuse to change types

Comment: Why not change `List<Object>` to `List<String>`? Or `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Object>`? They need to be the same type, otherwise you need to use bounds, like `List<? extends Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

1) `collection[i]` is an Array

2) if you wanted to write it like this:

`List<Object> collection;
 collection = new ArrayList<String>();`

You will get an `incompatible types: ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to List<Object>`

You can't covert String to Object. If you want it to be , you need to create it as a List of Strings. If you don't know what type you need, just create it when you will know. If it's user who chooses it, make a switch like this :

```
switch (entry) {
        case 1: {
            List<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            List<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<>();
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            List<Character> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        }

    }
```